# NullPointerException when using navigation-case

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, glassfish, jsf-2.2

I have this in my faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

When I go to the one of this pages, I get this exception:

```
Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.determineViewFromActionOutcome(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:1271)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.findWildCardMatch(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:660)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.getViewId(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:482)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.getNavigationCase(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:148)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.getNavigationCase(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getNavigationCase(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:146)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.encodeBegin(OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Line 1270 ([1200](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.1/com/sun/faces/application/NavigationHandlerImpl.java#1200) in 2.2.1) is

```
FlowHandler fh = ctx.getApplication().getFlowHandler();
```

It returns null and causes a NullPointerException on the next line.
Glassfish 4.0.0, JDK 1.7.0_40, JSF 2.2.4 (2.2.1 was before edits, but I didn't know that Glassfish had 2.2.0), Ubuntu 12.10 64bit. What's wrong?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I caught this error after fixing another error.

Comment: What's your source page ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand enough your question. Do you mean index.xhtml and login.xhtml?

Comment: No, there should be another page else ?

Comment: Where? These are the only XHTML-pages in project excepting master layout.

Comment: Yes, how many pages you have ?

Comment: Put also your `web.xml`.

Comment: Are you really using Mojarra 2.2.1? Line 1204 of `NavigationHandlerImpl` is just a `}` and that can impossibly cause a NPE.

Comment: I have two webpages and one for composition. BalusC, I can debug this class. result on line 1203 is: navCase = NavigationCase{fromViewId='*', fromAction='null', fromOutcome='login', if='null', toViewId='/login.xhtml', faces-redirect=true, includeViewParams=false', parameters=}, viewId = "/login.xhtml", isFlowEntryFromExplicitRule is false and all other are null.

Comment: Again catched this problem after another 500 error that was fixed.

Comment: Added some new info - code lines are OK now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluded CDI libraries from the artifact. Including was suggested by Idea.